# My security review fail because of a unit class : do managed packadge really need to contains unit test class?

Tags: unit-test, deployment, security-review

I'm wondering if the managed packadge need to contains all unit test class in the code base use to create de app.

I have herited from a code base and managed application and the app is released with all unit test class but one class fail.

Can I just remove the class?

I could just try but currently security review is a long process so I want to save time if someone can told me that unit class need to be in the packadge deployed.

Answer (score 2):

The review process takes about 6-8 weeks from when we have everything provided:
Your documentation is complete and accurate
The test environment is complete, fully configured, and includes all necessary information.
You have met the requirements
You are within the agreement guidelines

> Random Testing: Salesforce.com reserves the right to conduct random
>   on-site and off-site tests on published offerings. If during these
>   tests, we find that the offering has deviated from any of our
>   requirements, we will notify the publisher and provide a timeframe to
>   remedy the issue. In extreme cases, we may pull the AppExchange
>   listing from public viewing.

**Tests**: Use System.assert methods as much as possible to prove that code behaves properly. This is key to ensure that the Apex code executes to the expected value or behavior.

According to [Requirements Checklist](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Requirements_Checklist?language=en), It is always advisable to resolve the test failures and create a new managed package. Upload this new listing for a security review. This will avoid future consequences.